# Python: Letters to numbers not working correctly

Tags: python, string, function, return

So I have this project for school and I am so close to finishing it but there is one that I just cant seem to get to work properly. One of the functions I have is:

```
vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"

def alphapinDecode(tone):
   s = tone.lower()
   pin = ''

   for ch in s:
       if ch in consonants:
           idx = consonants.find(ch)
       elif ch in vowels:
           idx2 = vowels.find(ch)

           pin = str(pin) + str(idx*5 + idx2)




   print(pin)

   return None
```

For the most part the function runs exactly how I want it to. I take a string and it returns numbers as a string.

For example:

```
>>> alphapinDecode('bomelela')
3464140
```

But when I do this one:

```
>>>> alphapinDecode('bomeluco')
```

it returns 346448 instead of the 3464408 like it is supposed to do (according to my assignment). Now I know the function is giving me the correct answer based on the code, but what am I missing to have it include the 0 before the 8?

EDIT:

Function is supposed to take the string that you pass(tone) and break it up into 2 letter chunks(vowel/consonant pair). With the pair, it is supposed to use the pair and index them with vowels/consonants and return a number. >>>alphapinDecode('hi') returns 27 because consonants[h] gives idx = 5 while vowels[i] gives idx2 = 2

Comment: It would help if you explained what exactly your function is supposed to do, and how.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did...but its supposed to take the string that you pass(tone) and break it up into 2 letter chunks(vowel/consonant pair). With the pair, it is supposed to use the pair and index them with vowels/consonants and return a number.

>>>alphapinDecode('hi') 
returns 27 because consonants[h] gives idx = 5 while vowels[i] gives idx2 = 2

Comment: Please update your questions, then, so that other users know what to answer.

Comment: are u sure the indentation of pin = str(pin) + str(idx*5 + idx2) is correct? What are u trying to do with the idx*5 can u explain?

Comment: idx*5 is just the formula my class uses in the project. Regarding the indentation, I explained it up above just now.

Comment: @SteveDengZishi Actually, the indentation is correct, although it's not the way I'd approach the problem.

Comment: @Ken Y-N How would you approach it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your lecture trying to test students coding adaptability.
If really want achieve some output like that please try like below

```
vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"

def alphapinDecode(tone):
    s = tone.lower()
    pin = ''

for ch in s:
   if ch in consonants:
       idx = consonants.find(ch)
   elif ch in vowels:
       idx2 = vowels.find(ch)

       num = '%02d' % int((idx*5) + idx2) #python 2
       num = "{0:0=2d}".format((idx*5) + idx2) #python 3 more verbose
       pin = pin + str(num)

   print(int(pin))

   return None

alphapinDecode('bomeluco') # 3464408

alphapinDecode('bomelela') # 3464140
```

Comment: What is the '%02d' %?

Comment: @user2951723 **'%02d'** formats an integer 'd' to a field of minimum width 2, with zero-padding on the left(leading), the **second '%'** operator is called  [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) operator when used with a string on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perhaps awkward - I would iterate two characters at a time:

```
def alphapinDecode(tone):
   s = tone.lower()
   pin = ''

   # Step over the string two characters at a time
   for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
       ch1 = s[i]
       ch2 = s[i+1]
       if ch1 in consonants and ch2 in vowels:
           idx1 = consonants.find(ch1)
           idx2 = vowels.find(ch2)
           this_pair = idx1*5 + idx2
           # For debugging
           print(this_pair)
           pin = pin + str(this_pair)

   # We need to print without leading zeroes
   print(int(pin))

   # Returning the pin as an integer is better, IMO
   return int(pin)
```

OK, now we have the code looking a bit better, we can see, I hope, that for the `co` pair in your second text, the value is `1*5 + 3`, which equals `8`, of course, but you really want `08`. There's a number of ways to do this, but since you're a beginner I'll illustrate the easiest way.

```
this_pair = idx1*5 + idx2
if this_pair < 10:
    # If the pair is less than ten, prepend a leading zero
    this_pair_pin = '0' + str(this_pair)
else
    this_pair_pin = str(this_pair)
pin = pin + this_pair_pin
```

**EDIT**: Let's forget about accumulating the answer in a string as we can simplify the code:

```
pin = 0
#...
        this_pair = idx1*5 + idx2
        pin = pin * 100 + this_pair

print(pin)
```

Comment: Wouldnt this add a 0 in front of 3 though? So it ends up being 03464408

Comment: @user2951723 Ah, you are right, and I was wrong in a comment I deleted...